# Vuejs component couldn't access data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a simple component but I couldn't access data inside component

This is my component

```js
<template>
  <!-- success -->
  <div class="message-box message-box-success animated fadeIn" id="message-box-success">
    <div class="mb-container">
      <div class="mb-middle">
        <div class="mb-title"><span class="fa fa-check"></span>&nbsp;{{title}}&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="mb-content">
          <p>{{successMessage}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg pull-right mb-control-close" @click.prevent="close">OK</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end success -->

</template>

<script>
/* eslint-disable no-undef */

export default {
  name: 'SuccessMsg',
  props: {
    title: ''
  },
  data () {
    return {
      successMessage: 'success'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    show: function (message) {
      // in this line I'm getting undefined in console
      console.log(this.successMessage)
      // this.successMessage = message
      $('#message-box-success').addClass('open')
    },
    close: function () {
      $('#message-box-success').removeClass('open')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I have no problem in the other normal pages but in the component I couldn't access data.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's working for me. check here: https://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/bj5vggxv/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @IsraGab for your response and the code.
Your are right it's working but there is another problem that I didn't ask correctly.

It's not working when I'm calling the component method from main app in incorrect way.
After a day searching I find the solution.
Using [Component Refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Child-Component-Refs)

The correct way to calling method is:

```
this.$refs.errMsg.show('some messages')
```

Where we have component tag like this:

```
<v-error ref="errMsg"></v-error>
```

Thanks again to all